# Crash when SVG is used as small Icon for notification

Tags: android, svg, notifications, crash, statusbar

I've set a small icon to my notificaton builder using

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.location_off_24dp);
```

location_off_24dp is actually a SVG file in my project.

Issue is that I get crash with this code on pre-lollipop devices.

Crash report:

```
  android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.com.example.app: Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon(pkg=com.example.app.clientuser=0 id=0x7f02010e level=0 visible=true num=0 ) 
                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1410) 
                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426) 
                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I know we can use `app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_file"` in the layouts. But when we pass the SVG drawable resource ID to PendingIntent, will the system use something of srcCompat kind of version so it could apply to pre-lollipop too or it expects drawable to be a direct image ?

How do I use SVG as small Icon in Notification for pre-lollipop devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can have support for earlier versions of android by following steps as given in this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html).

Its better to use this guidelines to have support for multiple devices without inflation error.

Comment: I had read it but read it now to recap. PNG generation will happen only when vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = false in app's gradle. I have it true so it wont generate PNGs from vector file so at runtime it can not find them so the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Put the PNG's in drawable resource to reference them.
SVG crash in kitkat devices.